# Seeking a equivlanet RTC for replacing a BQ4285S RTC

Tags: rtc

I'm going to start a project that requires a BQ4285S RTC. The problem is finding a BQ4285S (other than from questionable sources in China directly) or equivalent replacement since I don't know if any of the variants of the BQ4285S series RTC's are a good equivalent. I'm a novice, and could use some help finding a solution so that I can build the intended project. Does anyone have some helpful input?

Comment: How about using a microcontroller with a built-in RTC?

Comment: What solutions you are after? Why do you need to use that specific RTC? If you are asking what to buy or from where, that's off-topic.

Comment: Perhaps I am off topic. I hope not. I was directed here by a representative from Jameco. I want to build a RTC solution that uses a CR1225 cell battery and a BQ4285S RTC to help an older laptop store CMOS configurations. Without a solution, the laptop won't boot. The existing solution in the laptop is no longer available. The project I am referencing is on Github. The project is nwX87.